# map non-object values in nested arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to map an array that has n-dimension sub-arrays. I've looked at deep-map but I'm not using any objects. An example of what I'm trying to do is:

```
    deepMap([4,5,[3,4,[2]]], (x) => x+5) 
    returns [9,10,[8,9,[7]]]
```

The function after the array in deepMap can be any function

```
        const deepMap=(arr, fn) =>{
            const stop = arr.length===0;
            const tail = arr.slice(1);
            const head = arr[0];
            const front = head instanceof Array ? [head[0]]: [] ;
            const next = fn(front, head);
            return stop ? [] : front.concat(deepMap(tail,fn));

        }
```

How do you apply a function to values in nested arrays while keeping the whole array a nested array?

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use simple recursion. For a nested array, map over the array calling `deepMap` recursively. When you reach a leaf, call the function.

```js
function deepMap(arr, fn) {
  return arr instanceof Array ? arr.map(el => deepMap(el, fn)) : fn(arr);
}
console.log(deepMap([4, 5, [3, 4, [2]]], (x) => x + 5));
```

Comment: thanks Barmar! I'm trying to not use if statements but that immensely, helped me visualize the process. I ended up with this:                            
          `const deepMap = (arr,fn) =>{
                const head = arr instanceof Array ? arr.map((el) => 
                   deepMap(el,fn)) : fn(arr);
                return head;
            }
            
            console.log(deepMap([4,5,[3,4,[2]]], (x) => x+5));` and it worked prefectly

Comment: You could use a ternary instead: `return arr instanceof Array ? ... : ...`

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows in a Haskellesque fashion;

```js
function deepMap([x,...xs],f){
  return x ? [Array.isArray(x) ? deepMap(x,f) : f(x), ...deepMap(xs,f)]
           : [];
}
  

var arr = [4,5,[3,4,[2]]],
    res = deepMap(arr, x => x+5);
console.log(res);
```